# Deploy a production build of an Angular app with Zeit Now

Tags: angular, angular8, vercel

I am using [zeit now](https://zeit.co/now) to deploy an Angular app. I followed [this tutorial](https://zeit.co/guides/deploying-angular-with-now).

I created the App using the Angular CLI. I developed it locally by using the command `ng serve`, and I deployed it by running `now`. Just as in the tutorial. However, the deployed code does not seem to be minified. If I look in the network tab of developer console, and read the javascript, it does not look minified, it looks just as I wrote it. For reference, my website can be found here https://peacefulprogramming.xyz/

#### My Questions

1) Does the `now` command make a production build of my app (equivalent to `ng build --prod`)?

2) If not, how can I get it to make a production build?

Comment: run `ng build --prod` to create prod build then cd to dist folder and then run `now`

Comment: @alt255 that didn't really work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy your application on **zeit** by using [@zeit/ng-deploy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zeit/ng-deploy) package. After angular cli 8.3.0 is released this will also support the `ng deploy` command. `ng deploy` command is currently available in `8.3.0_RC0`

Follow below steps :

**Add @zeit/ng-deploy to your project**

`ng add @zeit/ng-deploy`
You will be prompt to log in to **Now** account

**Deploy your project to Now**

`ng run [project_name]:deploy`

**This will create production build and then deploy then on zeit in single command**

After deploying your application you will see output similar to the following:

Your application is deployed at `https://[project-name]-1234.now.sh`